# Variable declaration in a compound conditional?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a style of ergonomic error checking I like for a lock-like object, but I'm having a little difficulty making it work when using a complex conditional statement.

```
struct Baton {
    struct Lock {
        operator bool() const;

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m_mx;
    };

    Lock lock();
};


int usage() {
    Baton baton;

    // this works okay!
    if (Baton::Lock lock = baton.lock()) {
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    } 

    // however I can't get this to compile...
    if (Baton::Lock lock = baton.lock(), bool(lock) && condition) {
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    } 
}
```

The conditional statement is intended to define a `Lock` object that lives as long as the if-else block, while also being utilized in the conditional statement, and not requiring external scoping to the if-else block.  But I can't seem to get my compiler to agree with me.

Is it possible to legally write this?

Comment: From C++17, yes, you can use [if with initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

Comment: @cigien - oh wow, thank you!  I had no idea this was a thing